# Autowired Service in Controller in Spring Boot , resultant is giving null

Tags: spring-boot, service, controller, autowired

I'm autowiring service class in my controller class, when I'm using it in my controller method it throw runtime exception saying service object is null, don't know what to do. please help

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/tree")
public class controller {

    @Autowired
    Service myService;

    @PostMapping
    private Object createObj(@RequestBody Object ques){
        Object save = myService.insert(ques);
        return save;
    }
}
```

resultant is runtime exception saying that 'myService is null'

Comment: Have you marked the Service class as @Service, or if it is an interface, have you marked any class implementing the interface with @Service? More info is required, we don't have a console output or any information about other classes. Please update you answer with more information to help us solve your problem.

Comment: Have you use @Service annotation on your service class and make sure your service class with in the package of project if it's out side use componentscan over main class and specify the  package

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that 'Service' you are importing is your own Service.
2. Make sure your 'Service' class is annotated with @Component or @Service...

Comment: My service class is annotated with @Service , despite that it is not working, please advise.

Comment: show more code then

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace private with public on your method in Controller

Comment: It worked, Thank you , may i know the reason behind it, please!

Comment: In the context of Spring Boot, methods that are part of components managed by the framework, such as controllers or services, need to be accessible from various parts of the application, including the Spring framework itself. By using the public access modifier, you ensure that these methods can be accessed by the Spring container and other components.

Answer (score -1):

Can you provide a link to a repo showing this in action? My guess is your service doesn't have an @Service (or @Component) annotation or that class is in another package that isn't getting picked up by scanning.

As a side note I would favor constructor injection and I have a video on this.

https://youtu.be/aX-bgylmprA